# c# dynamic sql looping through server command or linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, dynamic

Given a data set where you will only know the relevant fields at run time. I want to select each row of data for analysis through a loop. Is it better to:

1. run a direct sql query to get the row each time by directly opening and closing the database
2. pull all the applicable rows into a datatable before the loop then selecting them through linq from inside the loop

For example, I am reading in a file that says look for rows a b and c then my query becomes "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table WHERE col1 = 'a' or col1 = 'b' or col1= 'c'"
But I dont know it will be a,b,c during compile time, only after i run the program

Thanks

edit: better in terms or speed and best practice

Comment: Better in what terms? Apart from that it's really hard to undestand what you are trying to do

Comment: better in terms of standard practice and speed

Comment: please clarify: you are iterating over all rows, but you only know the relevant colums at runtime? could your analysis be expressed as SQL if you would know the relevant fields?

Comment: i know the relevant columns before but i only know the relevant rows at run time so im reading in a file which will say look for items a b and c

then my sql statement becomes select col 1, col 2, col3 where col1 = a or b or c

Answer (score 0):

depending on how long your analysis takes, the underlying transactional locking (if any), and the resources blocked by holding your result set on the db server it is either 1 or 2 ... but for me 2 seems rather unlikely (gigantic resultsets that are open for long periods of time and would eat up the memory on your DB system, which alone would suggest that you should rethink your whole data processing workflow)... i'd just build the SQL at runtime, which is even possible using linq directly against your DB (see "Entity Framework") and only if I would encounter serious performance problems once that is running, i'd refactor...

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow isn't really for "better" type questions because they're usually highly subjective/opinion based/lead to arguments.. We are however, free to decide whether subjective questions should be answered and this is one of those that (in my opinion) can

I'd assert that in 99% of cases you'd be better off leaving data in a database and querying it using the SQL functionality built into the database. The reason is that databases are purpose built for storing and querying data. It is somewhat ludicrous to conclude that it's a good use of resources to transfer 100 million rows across a network, into a poorly designed data storage container and then naively searching through it using a loop-in-a-loop (which is what linq in a loop would be) when you could leave it in the purpose-built, well indexed, high powered enterprise level software (on enterprise grade hardware) where it currently resides, and ask for retrieval of a tiny subset of those records to be transferred over a (slow) network link into a limited power client